# Prevent a Scala trait from qualifying as a SAM type

Tags: scala, implicit, single-abstract-method

I have a `trait Modifier[-A] extends (A => Unit)`.

However, Scala 2.12 magic SAM syntax silently converts any lambda literal like el => foo into a Modifier because Modifier qualifies as a SAM type (rules for applicability of this syntax are [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#sam-conversion)).

I don't want such conversion to apply to my Modifier trait because it interferes with my library's syntax. In short, I have an implicit conversion from `A => Modifier[A]` to `Modifier[A]`. With 2.12, that conversion is not triggered for lambda literals (e.g. `thisNode => someModifier(thisNode, otherParam)`) because Scala magicks the `A => Modifier[A]` lambda into a `Modifier[A]` all by itself, but not into a correct one.

There are a couple ways to solve this problem that I know of:

1) Modifier trait should not extend Function1, and should instead define its own abstract `def apply[X](element: El): Unit` method. SAM syntax is not applied due to the phantom type param X.

2) Add a meaningless abstract `protected[this] def foo` to Modifier trait. This will make SAM syntax inapplicable, and if I'm understanding Scala.js dead code elimination correctly, this bogus method will be eliminated from runtime.

I'm leaning towards Option 1 as it seems like less burden for implementers of Modifier, as well as more obvious that it will not affect runtime performance.

But it still seems hacky, and I don't like that the useless phantom type will leak into the API of my library. Isn't there a better way?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation of Scala 2.12 [Sam Conversions precedes implicits](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#sam-conversion-precedes-implicits) : the documentation also discuss potential solutions to override this behaviour.

If you need the conversion to occur automatically, both approaches are reasonable:

1. If you extend your own custom `MyFunction1` you might lose composition benefits of the standard library
2. If you add a meaningless method, you will fall back to a standard Function1 as soon as you perform combinatorial operations using the methods defined on `Function1`

In your case, I guess both approach are fine because your `Modifier apply` is returning Unit and you are not going to pipe or wire the operations together.