# Scala: Implicit conversion of a function doesn't work

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have this trait with a single method of type `WSResponse => HTTPCallResult[A]`

```
trait Parsable[A] {
  def parse(response: WSResponse): HTTPCallResult[A]
}
```

I want to define an implicit conversion from a function `WSResponse => A`

```
object Parsable {
  implicit class DefaultResponseParser[A](parser: WSResponse => A) extends Parsable[A] {
    override def parse(r: WSResponse): HTTPCallResult[A] = {
     //implementation
    }
  }
}
```

The desired behaviour is such, that if a function `WSResponse => HTTPCallResult[A]` is passed the anonymous class of Parsable[A] is automatically created. If a function of any other return type is passed (`WSResponse => A`) the implicit conversion is triggered.

However, an error occurs when compiling with SBT

```
[error] /Auth.scala:24:60: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : String
[error]  required: HTTPCall.HTTPCallResult[?]
[error]     (which expands to)  scala.util.Either[String,?]
[error]       .post((r: WSResponse) => (r.json \ "key").as[String])
```

This function was used in order to test it.

```
def post[A](parser: Parsable[A])
.post((r: WSResponse) => (r.json \ "key").as[String])
```

**EDIT 1:**
Even making the implicit class an implicit method and moving it to the very same scope as `post` didn't help.

**EDIT 2:**
It seems that the problem stems from the use of trait with single undefined method. Therefore when passed a function to the post method, the compiler tries to create an anonymous class of type Parser[A] from that. Due to a type missmatch it throws, without even trying to be looking for any implicits.

Comment: You have an implicit function that says, given a function `WSResponse => A` you can call `.parser(WSResponse)`. But, I guess, what you are trying to do is pass `WSResponse => A` instead of `Parsable[A]`.

Comment: @JohnyTKoshy yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve (instead of `Parser[A]` be able to pass just the function). If I can't achieve this by employing implicit method or class, how can I then?

Comment: I am not sure about the types here. If my assumptions are correct, following signature could work: `def post[A](p: WSResponse => A): WSResponse => HTTPCallResult[A] = p.parse(_)`

Comment: It seems that the problem stems from the single-method nature of the trait. Because  given a function of signature `WSResponse => HTTPCallResult[A]` the compiler tries to make an anonymous class from it, and fails when the types don't match. When I added a one more method to the trait, and thus made it unparsable, the implicit conversion worked. Somewhat the anonymous class parsing operation takes a precedence, and when it fails, the responsibility is not passed down to the implicits...

Comment: @DavidTomecek You're right, [SAM conversion precedes implicits](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#sam-conversion-precedes-implicits). See also [Prevent a Scala trait from qualifying as a SAM type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971622).

Comment: After going through the links @DmytroMitin provided if the parser function is referentially transparent, using `val parser: WSResponse => HTTPCallResult[A]` instead of using function definition would work in this case.